# Images stacking on top of each other

Tags: java, image, swing, button, stack

I am finishing up my DiceRollGUI, when I run it and press "Roll" the images stack of top of each other, how do I make so it disappears after I press the button again?

I did most of what MadProgrammer told me but I ran into errors which are:

```
--------------------Configuration: <Default>--------------------
G:\DiceRollGUI\src\DiceRollGUI.java:26: error: constructor RollButton in class RollButton cannot be applied to given types;
    button.addActionListener(new RollButton(diceRoll));
                             ^
required: JPanel
found: JLabel
reason: actual argument JLabel cannot be converted to JPanel by method invocation conversion
G:\DiceRollGUI\src\DiceRollGUI.java:42: error: cannot find symbol
        contentPane.add(diceRoll);
        ^
symbol:   variable contentPane
location: class RollButton
2 errors

Process completed.
```

[image: Dice Stack]

Code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class DiceRollGUI {
    public static JLabel label;
    public static JFrame frame;
    public static JPanel panel;
    private static JButton button;
    private static JButton buttonRollDie;
    private static JLabel diceRoll;

public static void main (String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Dice Roll GUI");
    panel = new JPanel();
    JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,2,5,10));
    button = new JButton("Roll");;

    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setSize(1000, 1000);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    button.setActionCommand("Roll");
    button.addActionListener(new RollButton(diceRoll));
    button.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(750, 500));
    frame.setContentPane(panel);
    frame.pack();
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
    panel.add(button);
}

    private static class RollButton implements ActionListener {

    private JPanel diceRoll;

    public RollButton(JPanel diceRoll){
        this.diceRoll = diceRoll;
        contentPane.add(diceRoll);
    }           
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            int roll = (int) (Math.round((Math.random() * 5) + 1));
            ImageIcon dice = null;

                if(roll == 1){
                    dice = new ImageIcon("DiceRollGUI Pictures/die_face_1.png");
                }
                else if(roll == 2){
                    dice = new ImageIcon("DiceRollGUI Pictures/die_face_2.png");
                }
                else if(roll == 3){
                    dice = new ImageIcon("DiceRollGUI Pictures/die_face_3.png");
                }
                else if(roll == 4){
                    dice = new ImageIcon("DiceRollGUI Pictures/die_face_4.jpeg");
                }
                else if(roll == 5){
                    dice = new ImageIcon("DiceRollGUI Pictures/die_face_5.png");
                }
                else if(roll == 6){
                    dice = new ImageIcon("DiceRollGUI Pictures/die_face_6.png");
                }
                JLabel diceRoll = new JLabel("",dice, JLabel.CENTER);
                panel.add(diceRoll);
                panel.revalidate(); 
            }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- In your constructor, create an instance of your `diceRoll` `JLabel` and add it to your `panel`

```
diceRoll = new JLabel();
contentPane.add(diceRoll);
```

2- Instead of passing a reference of your `contentPane` to the `RollButton` `ActionListener`, pass a reference to `diceRoll` instead...

```
button.addActionListener(new RollButton(diceRoll));
```

3- Change your `RollButton` `ActionListener` to support using a `JLabel` instead of a `JPanel`...

```
private static class RollButton implements ActionListener {

    private JLabel diceRoll;

    public RollButton(JLabel diceRoll){
        this.diceRoll= diceRoll;
    }
```

4- In your `actionPerformed` method, simply change the `diceRoll`'s icon property...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
    int roll = (int) (Math.round((Math.random() * 5) + 1));
    ImageIcon dice = null;
    //...
    diceRoll.setIcon(dice);
}
```

You may find using a `BorderLayout` or `GridBagLayout` on the `contentPane` produces a nice effect.  You may also want to investigate the `horizontalAligment` and `verticalAligment` properties

**Updated with compilable example**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DiceRollGUI {

    public static JLabel label;
    public static JFrame frame;
    public static JPanel panel;
    private static JButton button;
    private static JButton buttonRollDie;
    private static JLabel diceRoll;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Dice Roll GUI");
        panel = new JPanel();
        JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2, 5, 10));
        button = new JButton("Roll");

        // !! Add this !! //
        diceRoll = new JLabel();
        contentPanel.add(diceRoll);

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setSize(1000, 1000);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        button.setActionCommand("Roll");
        button.addActionListener(new RollButton(diceRoll));
        button.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(750, 500));
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.pack();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        panel.add(button);
    }

    private static class RollButton implements ActionListener {

        // !! Change This !! //
        private JLabel diceRoll;

        // !! Change This !! //
        public RollButton(JLabel diceRoll) {
            // !! Change This !! //
            this.diceRoll = diceRoll;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            int roll = (int) (Math.round((Math.random() * 5) + 1));
            ImageIcon dice = null;

            if (roll == 1) {
                dice = new ImageIcon("DiceRollGUI Pictures/die_face_1.png");
            } else if (roll == 2) {
                dice = new ImageIcon("DiceRollGUI Pictures/die_face_2.png");
            } else if (roll == 3) {
                dice = new ImageIcon("DiceRollGUI Pictures/die_face_3.png");
            } else if (roll == 4) {
                dice = new ImageIcon("DiceRollGUI Pictures/die_face_4.jpeg");
            } else if (roll == 5) {
                dice = new ImageIcon("DiceRollGUI Pictures/die_face_5.png");
            } else if (roll == 6) {
                dice = new ImageIcon("DiceRollGUI Pictures/die_face_6.png");
            }
            // !! Change This !! //
            diceRoll.setIcon(dice);
        }
    }
}
```

5- You never actually add `contentPane` to anything...Change your `main` to look more like..

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Dice Roll GUI");
    panel = new JPanel();
    JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2, 5, 10));
    button = new JButton("Roll");

    // !! Add this !! //
    diceRoll = new JLabel();
    contentPanel.add(diceRoll);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    button.setActionCommand("Roll");
    button.addActionListener(new RollButton(diceRoll));
    button.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(750, 500));
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
    panel.add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    panel.add(contentPanel);
    frame.setContentPane(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: No you didn't.  I said to change the `RollButton` to accept a `JLabel` and you haven't instantiated an instance of `diceRoll`, as suggested in the first point...

Comment: Okay I changed it so my RollButton ActionListener supports JLabel instead of JPanel but for the diceRoll.setIcon(dice); change it to what property? :\

Comment: Yeah I did change it to diceRoll.setIcon(dice), it compiles but nothing comes up after clicking the button.

Comment: You're not adding the `contentPane` to anything

Comment: Thank you for your tremendous help with all of this! I am very thankful :)

Answer (score 0):

Following your code, It seems that you add a new JLabel each time actionPerformed is call.
Once the Jlabel is added to the JPanel it stays in, you have to remove the previous one before :

```
panel.removeAll()
```

Comment: Yeah but if I put that in, it removes my button too

Comment: Then use the remove(int index) method, your button should be at index 0, then your first JLabel should be at index 1